# Validation cakePHP

Tags: validation, cakephp

I need to have the validation criteria for postcode. The validation should make sure that length of postcode is 4 and its all numbers. In my mySQL database postcode is set to VARCHAR 4 and Null. The code in my model is as follows:

```
   'customer_postcode' => array(
                'maximum' => array(
                    'rule' => array('numeric'),
                    'message' => 'Enter valid postcode'

                ),
                'minimum' => array(
                    'rule' => array('minLength','4'),
                    'message' => 'Minimum 4 characters long'

                ),
                ),
```

But when ever I try to add a customer without the postcode, it comes up saying "Enter valid postcode" even though it is set to null in the database.
How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting allowEmpty to true in order to accept a null value, [as described in the CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#allowempty).

Your code might look like this:

```
   'customer_postcode' => array(
                'maximum' => array(
                    'rule' => array('numeric'),
                    'message' => 'Enter valid postcode',
                    'allowEmpty' => true    
                ),
                'minimum' => array(
                    'rule' => array('minLength','4'),
                    'message' => 'Minimum 4 characters long'
                ),
                ),
```